# Estimate concurrent users per month in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, concurrent-users

How to calculate the maximum concurrent users of a website per month in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an article that has a solution for this:  [Checking Monthly Visits and Concurrent Users with Google Analytics](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/checking-concurrent-visitors-with-google-analytics/)

They suggest:

1. Viewing the Audience Overview report for the month in which you are interested.
2. Switching from "daily" to "hourly" stats at the top right
3. Using the graph to identify which hour has the highest traffic and record the number of visitors for that hour
4. Get the average time on site (in seconds) by changing the metric on the graph to "average time"
5. Plug those numbers into the formula:

   ```
   Concurrent Visitors = Hourly visitors * Time Spent on Site / 3600
   ```

Comment: Thank you Stephen. I have used this formula and got a result of some 4000 but the expectation is 12,000. Wondering if i can we breakdown the result further to get an idea

Comment: Concurrent users is usually measured for the purposes of preparing for maximum load.   Keep in mind that GA doesn't include bots which may put significant additional load on your servers.     The formula also assumes that the visitors within the peak hour are evenly distributed within that hour.   It may be that within that hour the visitors were actually concentrated within a few minutes.   That would be the case if your peak were from a flood of visitors from a a fresh news article, for example.

Comment: 4,000 to 12,000 simultaneous visitors is an awful lot, btw.   Congrats on a very popular site.